# Visual C# debugging step buttons grayed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with the Visual Studio 2015 (C#) debugger: When I start a test method, and it subsequently stops on an exception or a breakpoint, the debug buttons are sometimes grayed out (see figure 1). I can still use the function keys to step through the debugger, and the toolbar icons will often become available after a few keystrokes, or after trying to edit the code. Then the toolbar looks like figure 2, which is what I'd expect from the start.

[image: Before pressing any buttons]

[image: After pressing any buttons]

Comment: The first image doesn't appear to be debugging anything, given the "Start" option as opposed to the "Continue" option.

Comment: My guess is that the code is still compiling, prior to running the tests.

Comment: It is definitely not compiling - it had actually hit an exception when the first screenshot was taken. I notice now that even alt-tabbing out of Visual Studio and back again puts it to the correct state (as in figure 2).